# Is a TODAY() value in a formula field updated every day?

Tags: formula-field, date

I want to use `TODAY()` in a formula field to calculate a person’s age based on the value in their date of birth field. Then I need to pull this field into a report. Will the `TODAY()` value be updated every day? Is there any other way I can calculate age in a report?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All formula fields are calculated at run time.  No value is stored on the record for a formula field.

This means that any time you view a record, either through the UI or a report, the formula is calculated at the time you run it.

In short, yes.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so but wasn't sure.